# Javascript: refactoring existing code to separate concerns, how could we use a class/Prototype and call from it own objects' methods?

Tags: javascript, file, object, refactoring, prototype

I have a web page where I show two models, each one in a canvas using Threejs.

I would like to read a local file, parse it and then make it avaliable to download.

I have done it, all mixed, I mean the logic is having both the responsability to show the canvas and to read, parse, and download the file.

I would like to isolate file read, parse and download logic into another class. Currently I extracted out the canvas' show logic in a class called InitCanvas.js

Here is the code:

```
// this class handles the load and the canva for a nrrd
// Using programming based on prototype: https://javascript.info/class
// This class should be improved:
//   - Canvas Width and height

InitCanvas = function (IdDiv, Filename) {


    this.IdDiv = IdDiv;
    this.Filename = Filename
}

InitCanvas.prototype = {

    constructor: InitCanvas,

    init: function () {

        this.container = document.getElementById(this.IdDiv);

        // this should be changed.
        this.container.innerHeight = 600;
        this.container.innerWidth = 800;

        //These statenments should be changed to improve the image position
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, this.container.innerWidth / this.container.innerHeight, 0.01, 1e10);
        this.camera.position.z = 300;

        let scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.add(this.camera);

        // light

        let dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
        dirLight.position.set(200, 200, 1000).normalize();

        this.camera.add(dirLight);
        this.camera.add(dirLight.target);


        // read file

        let loader = new THREE.NRRDLoader();
        loader.load(this.Filename, function (volume) {

            //z plane
            let sliceZ = volume.extractSlice('z', Math.floor(volume.RASDimensions[2] / 4));

            this.container.innerWidth = sliceZ.iLength;
            this.container.innerHeight = sliceZ.jLength;

            sliceZ.mesh.material.color.setRGB(0,1,1);


            console.log('Our slice is: ', sliceZ);

            scene.add(sliceZ.mesh);
        }.bind(this));


        this.scene = scene;

        // renderer

        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true});
        this.renderer.setPixelRatio(this.container.devicePixelRatio);
        this.renderer.setSize(this.container.innerWidth, this.container.innerHeight);

        // add canvas in container
        this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);





    },

    animate: function () {

        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    }

}
```

*So the idea is to refactor the logic.js:*

```
if (!Detector.webgl) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

// global variables for this scripts
let OriginalImg,
    SegmentImg;

var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mousePressed = false;
var clickCount = 0;
var allText;


init();
animate();
readTextFile("columna01-es-latin1.txt");


// initilize the page
function init() {


    let filename = "models/nrrd/columna01.nrrd"; // change your nrrd file
    let idDiv = 'original';
    OriginalImg = new InitCanvas(idDiv, filename);
    OriginalImg.init();
    console.log(OriginalImg);

    filename = "models/nrrd/columnasegmentado01.nrrd"; // change your nrrd file
    idDiv = 'segment';
    SegmentImg = new InitCanvas(idDiv, filename);
    SegmentImg.init();
}

let originalCanvas = document.getElementById('original');
originalCanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
originalCanvas.addEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);


function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
    mousePressed = true;

    clickCount++;

    mouse.x = ( ( event.clientX - OriginalImg.renderer.domElement.offsetLeft ) / OriginalImg.renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -( ( event.clientY - OriginalImg.renderer.domElement.offsetTop ) / OriginalImg.renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1

    console.log('Mouse x position is: ', mouse.x, 'the click number was: ', clickCount);
    console.log('Mouse Y position is: ', mouse.y);

    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse.clone(), OriginalImg.camera);
    var objects = raycaster.intersectObjects(OriginalImg.scene.children);

    console.log(objects);
}

function onDocumentMouseUp(event) {
    mousePressed = false
}


function animate() {


    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    OriginalImg.animate();
    SegmentImg.animate();


}

function readTextFile(file) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
            if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                allText = rawFile.responseText;
                console.log('The complete text is', allText);
                let lineArr = intoArray(allText);
                let firstLineWords = intoWords(lineArr[0]);
                let secondLineWords = intoWords(lineArr[1]);

                console.log('Our  first line is: ', lineArr[0]);

                let atlas = {};
                for (let i = 0; i < firstLineWords.length; i++) {
                    console.log(`Our ${i} word in the first line is : ${firstLineWords[i]}`);
                    console.log(`Our ${i} word in the SECOND line is : ${secondLineWords[i]}`);
                    atlas[firstLineWords[i]] = secondLineWords[i];
                }
                console.log('The atlas is: ', atlas);
                let atlasJson = JSON.stringify(atlas);
                console.log('Atlas as json is: ', atlasJson);

                download(atlasJson, 'atlasJson.txt', 'text/plain');
            }
        }
    };
    rawFile.send(null);
}

// Function to download data to a file
function download(text, name, type) {
    var a = document.getElementById("a");
    var file = new Blob([text], {type: type});
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.download = name;
}


function intoArray(lines) {
    // splitting all text data into array "\n" is splitting data from each new line
    //and saving each new line as each element*

    var lineArr = lines.split('\n');

    //just to check if it works output lineArr[index] as below


    return lineArr;


}

function intoWords(line) {


    var wordsArr = line.split('" "');


    return wordsArr;
}
```

To extract out readTextFile, download, intoArray, intoWords in its own class.

I have tried the following, as a new class, called myFileReader:

```
MyFileReader = function () {



}

MyFileReader.prototype = {

    constructor: MyFileReader,

    readTextFile: function (file, intoLines, intoWords) {

        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
                if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                    allText = rawFile.responseText;
                    console.log('The complete text is', allText);
                    let lineArr = this.intoLines(allText);
                    let firstLineWords = this.intoWords(lineArr[0]);
                    let secondLineWords = this.intoWords(lineArr[1]);

                    console.log('Our  first line is: ', lineArr[0]);

                    let atlas = {};
                    for (let i = 0; i < firstLineWords.length; i++) {
                        console.log(`Our ${i} word in the first line is : ${firstLineWords[i]}`);
                        console.log(`Our ${i} word in the SECOND line is : ${secondLineWords[i]}`);
                        atlas[firstLineWords[i]] = secondLineWords[i];
                    }
                    console.log('The atlas is: ', atlas);
                    let atlasJson = JSON.stringify(atlas);
                    console.log('Atlas as json is: ', atlasJson);

                    this.download(atlasJson, 'atlasJson.txt', 'text/plain');
                }
            }
        };
        rawFile.send(null);
    },

    download: function (text, name, type) {

        var a = document.getElementById("a");
        var file = new Blob([text], {type: type});
        a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        a.download = name;
    },
    intoLines: function (text) {
        // splitting all text data into array "\n" is splitting data from each new line
        //and saving each new line as each element*

        var lineArr = text.split('\n');

        //just to check if it works output lineArr[index] as below


        return lineArr;


    },
    intoWords: function (lines) {


        var wordsArr = lines.split('" "');


        return wordsArr;

    },

};
```

*And I am using it from logic.js as:*

```
myFileReader = new MyFileReader();
myFileReader.readTextFile("columna01-es-latin1.txt");
```

Here is the question:

**1. Why do we get:**

```
TypeError: this.intoLines is not a function
```

Which is refered to the line:

```
            let lineArr = this.intoLines(allText);
```

In addition, to solve this error I have also tried to pass in the function from the object as:

logic.js:

```
myFileReader = new MyFileReader();
myFileReader.readTextFile("columna01-es-latin1.txt", myFileReader.intoLines(), myFileReader.intoWords());
```

And in our class, myFileReadder.js, inside readtTextFile we put:

```
let lineArr = intoLines(allText);
let firstLineWords = intoWords(lineArr[0]);
let secondLineWords = intoWords(lineArr[1]);
```

And our web console tells us:

```
TypeError: text is undefined
```

I understand that text is undefined because in logic.js we are not providing it:

```
myFileReader.readTextFile("columna01-es-latin1.txt", myFileReader.intoLines(), myFileReader.intoWords());
```

However I think we can not provide it, because we are in fact requesting to myFileReader that reads all the text from the local file and pass it in to intoLines() method.

**2. Why does it happen, and how could we solve it?**

Thank you for your help!

EDIT:

The final code after @Bergi suggestion is:

```
function readTextFile(file) {

    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
            if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                allText = rawFile.responseText;
                console.log('The complete text is', allText);
                let lineArr = intoLines(allText);
                let firstLineWords = intoWords(lineArr[0]);
                let secondLineWords = intoWords(lineArr[1]);

                console.log('Our  first line is: ', lineArr[0]);

                let atlas = {};
                for (let i = 0; i < firstLineWords.length; i++) {
                    console.log(`Our ${i} word in the first line is : ${firstLineWords[i]}`);
                    console.log(`Our ${i} word in the SECOND line is : ${secondLineWords[i]}`);
                    atlas[firstLineWords[i]] = secondLineWords[i];
                }
                console.log('The atlas is: ', atlas);
                let atlasJson = JSON.stringify(atlas);
                console.log('Atlas as json is: ', atlasJson);

                download(atlasJson, 'atlasJson.txt', 'text/plain');
            }
        }
    };
    rawFile.send(null);
}

function download(text, name, type) {

    var a = document.getElementById("a");
    var file = new Blob([text], {type: type});
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.download = name;
}

function intoLines(text) {
    // splitting all text data into array "\n" is splitting data from each new line
    //and saving each new line as each element*

    var lineArr = text.split('\n');

    //just to check if it works output lineArr[index] as below


    return lineArr;


}

function intoWords(lines) {


    var wordsArr = lines.split('" "');


    return wordsArr;

}
```

I have also studied:

**Prototype:  This thread helped me a lot**

[How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

**How to download files to local storage**

[JavaScript: Create and save file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file)

**How we delete properties from an object**
[How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does it happen, and how could we solve it?

See [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572).

> I have tried the following, as a new class

There's your issue. There's no reason to use a class construct at all, you're not going to instantiate it and keep data on the objects.

Yes, it's a good idea to extract out readTextFile, download, intoArray, intoWords into its own module, in its own file. But there's no reason to use an (empty!) constructor and a prototype, just plain functions would do fine (and you also wouldn't have above problem with accessing instance methods).

Comment: Thank you @Bergi I have done what you suggested and it is correct, plain functions are good here.